# What is the equivalent to the label tag for spans and buttons?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some form controls that I'm using label tags with, but there are also 2 columns in the row that aren't input forms so label tags aren't working correctly - a static label field, and a save button.
The values are floating right next to the labels rather than underneath. What can I use as an alternative?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty0Ln19p/)

```
<div class="list-group list-group-large list-group-background list-group-background-data settings">
  <div class="list-group-header">
    <div class="list-group-title">
      <h3>Set Alerts</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-large list-group-data">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="alarm in alarms">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Field</label>
        <select ng-model=alarms[$index].name class="form-control">
          <option ng-repeat="header in headers" value="{{header[0]}}">{{header[0]}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Condition</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model=alarms[$index].variant class="selectpicker">
          <option ng-selected="alarm.variant == 'gt'" value="gt">is greater than</option>
          <option ng-selected="alarm.variant == 'lt'" value="lt">is less than</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Threshold</label>
        <input ng-model=alarms[$index].threshold type="text" class="form-control threshold" value="{{alarm.threshold}}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Units</label>
        <span>deg</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Save</label>
        <button type="button" ng-show="$last" ng-click="pushThreshold()" class="btn btn-success-outline">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The values are floating right next to the labels rather than underneath.  Sorry I'll add that

Comment: Why would a button need a label?

Comment: `label` elements should have a `for` attribute whose value is the `id` of the form control (or wrap the label and form element) in order to link the two for accessibility. See [the guidance from the w3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to use this code:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon" id="contactField1" >Name</span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="write Name" aria-describedby="contactField1">
</div>
```

This will add a nice label with "Name" on the right side of input component

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `<span>` tag to a `<div>` tag and wrapped the button inside a `<div>` tag and it worked.